# POST request not executing inside @JMSListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms

I have Spring and ActiveMQ, and I'm using JMS to send/receive messages. Sending (`JMSTemplate`) and receiving  (`@JMSListener`) messages is ok. I have one consumer that needs to make a POST request to a webservice with the JMS message as the payload. When the message is received by the consumer it seems the POST does not execute. There are no errors thrown and no response 200, 40X, 50X, etc. I can use the same POST code in other classes with success so I am missing something about the consumer behavior. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```java
@Bean 
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> factoryeventQueue(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory(); 
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(1);
  
    return factory; 
}
```

```
@Service
public class JmsReceiveAndPost {

    private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("myLogger");
    private ResponseEntity<String> result;

    @JmsListener(destination = "eventQueue", containerFactory = "factoryeventQueue")
    public void onMessage(String message, Message inMessage, Session session) {

        logger.debug("eventQueue  Incoming message ");
        try {

            URI uri = new URI("http://127.9.0.1:8443/data");
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, inMessage, String.class);
            logger.debug("POST response: " + result.getStatusCode());

        } catch (RestClientException e) {
             logger.error("Error " + e);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            logger.error("Error " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `RestTemplate` doesn't care where it is called from; I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging to see if it provides any clues. Perhaps `inMessage` is not compatible with whatever converters you have configured in the `RestTemplate`. It's unusual to try to send an unconverted JMS `Message` over HTTP.

Comment: I got it working. changed Service to Component suggested by a colleague.  thanks for the response.